# Abnormal difference between Timestamp and UTC milliseconds

Tags: java, mysql, timestamp, jodatime

I have a simple database table with one BigInt and a Timestamp field. I am inserting the current UTC milliseconds into the database BigInt field while the Timestamp is generated by mysql using CURRECT_TIMESTAMP. My SQL is set to UTC timezone and i am new to all this:).

The trouble is logically the timestamp and milliseconds should be same but they are not. I am using jodatime.

```
if(rs.next())
        {
            Long milliseconds = rs.getLong("milliseconds");
            Timestamp ts = rs.getTimestamp("timestamp");



            System.out.println("milliseconds = " + new DateTime(milliseconds, DateTimeZone.UTC ));
            System.out.println("milliseconds = " + milliseconds);

            System.out.println("timestamp raw = " + ts);    


            System.out.println("difference = " +( milliseconds - ts.getTime()));    

        }
```

This gives me :

```
milliseconds = 2016-07-28T18:17:35.748Z
milliseconds = 1469729855748
timestamp raw = 2016-07-28 18:17:36.12174
difference = 19799627
```

As you see  milliseconds and timestamp raw are same, but their difference gives me 19799627. There is not even a second of difference but it says there is huge difference.

So i need 2 thinsg:

1. Some how match the two. how can i get the two to be same ?
2. If mysql time zone is changed and i know the timezone, how can i convert the Timestamp to match the milliseconds. ? Basically there should not be a difference of more than a second, but i cannot get it right. Please help out.

Comment: `2016-07-28T18:17:35.748Z` and `2016-07-28 18:17:36.12174` is not in the same *time zone*. According to `difference`, they are 5.5 hours apart, which likely means that your VMs default timezone is UTC+05:30 [India]. The JDBC driver converted to local timezone, so the `Timestamp` would represent the same *local* time as was stored in the database. Handling of mixed time zones is a complex issue, so you should search for articles about that.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. But tell me one thing.. they do look the same to me as HH MM SS goes. also can you give me any hint on how to make sure timestamp is always in UTC ? with or without touching mysql settings ?

Comment: How about using `new DateTime(TimeStamp.getTime(), DateTimeZone.UTC)`?

Comment: milliseconds = 2016-07-28T18:17:35.748Z
zone = UTC
timestamp = 2016-07-28T12:47:36.121Z
zone = UTC

still they look completely different even though both were inserted simultaneously

Comment: As I already said, time zone handling for SQL (i.e. when using JDBC) is a complex issue, and *you should really search for articles about that*. --- `Timestamp` does not carry a time zone. `java.util.Date`, `java.sql.Date` and `java.sql.Timestamp` all store time as epochMillisUTC. A time zone is applied when the value is displayed, and will generically use the JVM default time zone, unless otherwise specified. Database connections will usually convert values from the servers time zone to the JVM time zone, again unless otherwise specified. This is what you're experiencing.